# Что лучше использовать parseInt или Number?

Tags: ecmascript, javascript

В своем веб-приложении использую такую конструкцию:

```
prompt('Введите координату x:',40)
```

И тут я подумал, что мне стоит перестраховаться и обезапасить себя, подключив проверку того, что вводит пользователь, мне нужно сделать проверку, что вводятся именно числовые данные. Что лучше использовать parseInt или Number? Есть ли между ними разница? В старом учебнике по JS везде используется Number. Или такую проверку вообще не имеет смысла делать?

Comment: Черт, опоздал я. Могли бы на эту тему со Spectre похоливарить :-)

Comment: я пытался найти нашу прошлую дискуссию, но безрезультатно

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, стоит ли prompt('Введите координату x:',40) обрамлять в parseInt или Number - для проверки? По идее люди должны вводить только числа, но могут же ввести, что угодно. Очень интересно услышать Ваше мнение.

Comment: Стоит забыть про prompt и вводить данные в input type="text", реализуя валидацию ввода. И учесть еще наличие в html5 типов range и number, а также атрибуты pattern, min, max...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Разница есть:

```
var a = Number("123a");//a - NaN
var b = parseInt("123a");//b - 123
var c = parseFloat("123a");//c - 123

var d = Number("12.12");//d - 12.12
var e = parseInt("12.12");//e - 12
var f = parseFloat("12.12");//f - 12.12

var g = Number("12.12asd");//g - NaN
var h = parseInt("12.12asd");//h - 12
var i = parseFloat("12.12asd");//i - 12.12
```

Ну в общем понятно. parse пытается преобразовать первые символы к типу, а Number берет всю строку... Что использовать - зависит от задачи.

Comment: лучше без `new`, иначе:

    parseInt('12') === new Number('12') // false

Comment: Number - float ili double. Int - i v africe int

Comment: @Spectre, спасибо поправил.

Comment: @semenvx27 Number("0xFF") - это float или double?

Comment: кстате, ещё можно использовать унарный минус 

- `'12' - 0 // 12`
- `'12.12' - 0 // 12.12`
- `'123a' - 0 // NaN`

Comment: @Spectre можно использовать любую арифметическую операцию (кроме плюса). `'12'/1` или `'12.12'*1` дадут то же приведение типов.

Comment: резюмирую: автоматическое приведение типов эквивалентно поведению `Number(string)`

    +'12' === 12 // true
    +'12.12' === 12.12 // true
    isNaN(+'123a') // true

Answer (score 3):

[[@eprivalov1](/users/6953/eprivalov1)](/users/6953/eprivalov1), тезисы потеряны, но я бы стал использовать:

- `Number(string)` если ожидается ввод неспецифического десятичного числа
- `parseInt(string, radix)` если ожидается ввод целого в известной системе счисления
- `parseFloat(string)` если ожидается ввод действительного числа

В целом, `Number(string)` обеспечивает наиболее строгое "преобразование", parseXXX игнорируют символы, которые не принадлежат числу. ср. `parseInt('42fnord')`.

JS - безтиповой язык, но не следует этим злоупотреблять, в вашем случае лучше получить статус ошибки (а это

```
var badNumber = isNaN( Number(string) );
```

) как можно раньше, т.е. на этапе ввода данных.

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам за ответ, Вы внесли ясность в понимании мной этого вопроса!

Comment: Приглашаю оппонировать, чтобы это осталось обсужденным и можно было в будущем ссылаться.

Comment: Сейчас сделал вот так - Number(prompt('Введите координату X:',40)) и parseInt(prompt('Введите координату Y:',200)). Когда ввожу, что попало - символы, например, просто ничего не происходит. Однако я сейчас работаю в Ubuntu, браузер FireFox 3.6.10. Нужно в Винде попробовать в современном браузере.

Comment: А что должно происходить?

Comment: Незнаю, думал будет ошибку выдавать...

Comment: Ошибки не будет. Функция что одна что другая на невалидный ввод вернет [NaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_nan.asp).

Comment: @karmadro4, я с вами соглашусь, т.к. в текущей практике отказался от использования `parseXXX`

Comment: @eprivalov1, немного дополнил про статус ошибки, но это уже офф-топик в данном случае.

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt()` говорит сама за себя: сначала она парсит строку, выделяя из неё все цифры до первой буквы, а уже затем преобразует в число с типом постпредиката. Такое, например, работает некорректно:

```
 <script>
 var a = parseInt("12as45");
 alert(a);  // 12
 </script>
```

У функции также есть необязательный второй параметр "radix", указывающий на тип системы счисления, числа(буквы) которой предстоит искать. Для 16-ричной, например, буквы A-F будут считаться числами.

Comment: пропуск второго аргумента иногда приводит к интересным последсвиям:

    parseInt('07')// 7
    parseInt('08')// 0